# Firebase emulators:exec --only firestore not executing the script given as parameter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I used to run the following command to run some tests against a emulated firestore instance:

`firebase emulators:exec --only firestore 'npm test'`

Since my upgrade to `"firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"` and `"firebase-functions-test": "^0.3.3"' this doesn't execute my tests anymore. And after a minute gives me:
Error: TIMEOUT: Port 8080 on localhost was not active within 60000ms

Running `firebase emulators:start --only firestore` works fine. And if I change the command above to `firebase emulators:exec --only auth 'npm test'` the execution works as expected, but obviously the tests fail.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: What's your Node version?

Comment: @Gourav B, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The problem only occurs with Node 17, with node 14 or 16 the execution runs fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Gourav B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16313960/gourav-b) asked me what node version I was on. I figured I would try to run it with different versions I had installed.

Version 17 was the default one, and would still not work.
I quickly changed to 14 and the `firebase emulators:exec --only firestore 'npm test'` would run smoothly.

Also node version 16 doesn't have any problems.

As a tip to people reading this: To quickly switch between node versions I personally use [Node Version Manager (nvm)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: Indeed it was different node versions in the 2 terminal windows I had. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason for receiving this error in Firebase emulators might be due to a number of reasons. I would try to bring out all the possible solutions to resolve this through this answer.

- Extend the duration of your Cloud Functions. Follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout).
- You may try specifying the host as "127.0.0.1" instead of the default
  ‘localhost’.
  Firebase.json should look like this:

```
  { 
    "Firestore":
     { 
      "rules": "firestore.rules", 
      "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
     },
   "Emulators":
     { 
       "Firestore":
          { 
            "port": 8080, 
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
          }, 
      "Ui":
          { 
           "enabled": true
          }
       }
    }
```

- Sometimes, reverting back to the previous version fixes, as suggested
  in the [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57070483/firebase-serve-only-functions-doesnt-work).
- You could try running the Firestore emulator JAR directly and see if
  it works for you.

Comment: thanks for answering! as explained: firestore runs but the emulators:exec command doesn't run the specified script after starting firestore. due to emulators:exec the firestore-emulator waits for a minute and then exits, because no requests (from the script) have been made.

Comment: You may have a look at this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996172/unable-to-connect-to-firebase-emulator-suite-with-exec). Let me know if that helps!

Comment: it was because I was running it with node version 17. The command doesn't seem to work there yet. node 16 and below worked.
Thanks for answering!